# Cant Install Laravel with Docker on Windows WSL

Tags: laravel, windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I can't seem to install the new laravel with Docker Desktop on Windows 10.

What I did so far:

I installed Docker Setup with WSL2.
then I installed Ubuntu Distro from Ms Store.
then on command prompt terminal I run `wsl` command then when I tried to run `curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash` I got this error `-sh: curl: not found`.

I can't event use the apt command, it gives the same error.
The only working command is `ls`

WSL integration options on Docker Desktop are already checked

Am I missing something here? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the curl command is not installed in your Ubuntu WSL distribution. You can install it by running the following command in your WSL terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install curl
```

This should install curl and allow you to run the curl command to download the Laravel installer script.

If you're still having trouble using apt, it's possible that your Ubuntu WSL distribution is not properly installed or configured. You may want to try reinstalling or resetting it.

Once you have curl installed, try running the Laravel installer script again with the curl command:

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
```

This should create a new Laravel application in a directory called example-app.

If you're still having trouble, you can try using the Docker image for Laravel instead of installing it directly on your machine. The official Laravel Docker image includes everything you need to get started with Laravel in a containerized environment.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by changing this:

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
```

to:

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this was the missing step on Windows 10:

Run `wsl --install` to set up the default linux distro (Ubuntu).

You can show all distros by running `wsl --list --online`